Remove Specific Word From String
I have a requirement where I have to remove a part of a string as follows:
string input = "SELECT ENTERPRISE_ID enterpriseId, ENTERPRISE_NAME enterpriseName, EMAIL email, DATEFORMATSTR dateFormatStr, TO_CHAR(DELETEDON,'HH:MI:SS AM') TIME, DELETEDON FROM LOG_FILE_DELETION_DATA WHERE AND COLNAME = '' AND";

The first occurrence of AND after WHERE clause should be removed. I tried the below that could remove it:
public static string RemoveWord(string str, int start, int end)
{
  return str.Substring(0, start) + str.Substring(end, str.Length - end).Trim();
} 

The issue with the above is that, when it checks the length for the above string with the query, the length is 186. Though the length is more than that. I don't know why this occurred, but is there any better way that I can eliminate the first occurrence of the AND after WHERE clause?

Do you mean you want to replace first "WHERE AND" phrase with just "WHERE"? Can other words be between WHERE and AND?

Can you please show expected output? Several possible input strings would help too.

Others should be there, expected output - SELECT ENTERPRISE_ID enterpriseId, ENTERPRISE_NAME enterpriseName, EMAIL email, DATEFORMATSTR dateFormatStr, TO_CHAR(DELETEDON,'HH:MI:SS AM') TIME, DELETEDON FROM LOG_FILE_DELETION_DATA WHERE COLNAME = '' AND.

One way to debug things is to split up that long expression in the return statement. Compute subexpressions in separate variables so that you can view them in the debugger or print them to the console. That way you can get a better idea of where things are going wrong. Your debugger is a powerful tool. Learn to use it.

Re your addition: Please put all additional info in the question itself, not in comments.

The easiest option is to Replace("WHERE AND", "WHERE"), fiddle.

Please [edit] your question to include the expected output (don't just leave it as a comment, it's too important!)  Also, that string looks like SQL.  Have you considered the dangers of performing string replacement on SQL commands? For example, if that were OR instead of AND and you blindly replaced OR then you might replace part of FOREIGN KEY which itself contains OR.  Or what if the text AND appears in a string literal within the syntax of some future version of your SQL code? (I realize you don't have one at the moment.)  I guess this is just a cautionary remark.

Usually if you're having to do this, it's a band-aid over an existing problem, and you're better off fixing whatever's creating that "AND" in the first place.

Also note that the comment from @JimMischel is a good one. Many folks try do do everything in a single line of code believing that is somehow better than clearer code with an additional variable or two (to simplify debugging). Remember that in a release build, the compiler is very likely going to remove those temporary variables you put in to document and debug your code.

Where does that first AND come from? It looks like it was generated by concatenation of filters (" AND this" + " AND that").
A trick is to use not just WHERE before the filter clauses, but WHERE 1=1 - so the first AND is fine (even required) and (bonus) the command will still work when there are no filters.

This is a good trick, I believe I should try this. Thanks @Hans Keﬆing.

Now that we have the desired output, you can use a simple Replace call:
string input = "SELECT ENTERPRISE_ID enterpriseId, ENTERPRISE_NAME enterpriseName, EMAIL email, DATEFORMATSTR dateFormatStr, TO_CHAR(DELETEDON,'HH:MI:SS AM') TIME, DELETEDON FROM LOG_FILE_DELETION_DATA WHERE AND COLNAME = '' AND";

string result = input.Replace("WHERE AND ", "WHERE ");

Demo Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9dLsGv
This will replace all WHERE AND  occurrences instead of just one, but given that this is a SQL query it is only better this way, just in case it's needed with subqueries and all.

From the comments, the OP responded to the question "Can other words be between WHERE and AND?" that there could be: "Others should be there..." i.e., a simple Replace call on "WHERE AND" might not work.
Perhaps using a Regular Expression might be required:
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "SELECT ENTERPRISE_ID enterpriseId, ENTERPRISE_NAME enterpriseName, EMAIL email, DATEFORMATSTR dateFormatStr, TO_CHAR(DELETEDON,'HH:MI:SS AM') TIME, DELETEDON FROM LOG_FILE_DELETION_DATA WHERE AND COLNAME = '' AND";
        string result = RemoveFirstAndAfterWhere(input);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static string RemoveFirstAndAfterWhere(string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"(WHERE\b.*?)\bAND\s*";
        return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}

Output:
SELECT ENTERPRISE_ID enterpriseId, ENTERPRISE_NAME enterpriseName, EMAIL email, DATEFORMATSTR dateFormatStr, TO_CHAR(DELETEDON,'HH:MI:SS AM') TIME, DELETEDON FROM LOG_FILE_DELETION_DATA WHERE COLNAME = '' AND

Try on godbolt.org

a simple string.Replace won't solve it, because string.Replace will only replace the first occurrence of a given string, which would be an issue if the query contains a correlated query. StringBuilder.Replace would solve this issue.
var builder = new StringBuilder(input);

builder.Replace(" WHERE AND ", " WHERE ");

var result = builder.ToString();

Since StringBuilder.Replace is case-sensitive, you may experience an issue with some queries that were written in different casing than the given string.
To solve it, you can use Regex.Replace as @Sash-Sinha suggested.
Regex.Replace(input, @"(WHERE\b.*?)\bAND\s*", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

Using RegexOptions.IgnoreCase would solve the issue, and RegexOptions.Compiled would compile the expression for faster execution.
StringBuilder.Replace is much faster than Regex.Replace, but it's also uses twice the memory size more than Regex.Replace.
If the queries are hard-coded, meaning it's maintained by the developers, then Regex.Replace would be a safer option here. However, if your queries are dynamically generated by some SQL builder at runtime, then StringBuilder.Replace can be used if you are 100% sure that the reserved words will have the same case.
